# some php file work and not others with the same permissions

Tags: php, nginx

I have installed Oracle Linux 8 /PHP /Apache. All is working okay with one problem. Only some of my php scrip files will run others give permission denied. I **have set the correct permissions on the files**.

Example: In doc root www/html I can run phpinfo.php no problem but if I add a test.php same file permissions same location www/html and put ( phpinfo(); ) in it, I get permissions denied. If I change the contents of phpinfo.php and add a query for example, it works.

Its like the file name is allowed for certain file names but not allowing other file names. Again, file permissions are all correct. In fact I set them to 777 just for testing but got the same results.

Best I can tell is its something to do with nginx and php-fpm but I can't find out why its doing this. I don't have any experience with php-fpm or nginx only what I learned today. I looked for anything in php-fpm and nginx config files that would be related to this. Also, googled all day :/

```
sudo grep -i denied /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Results

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1689293825.039:334): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=5111 comm="php-fpm" name="test.php" dev="dm-0" ino=18674742 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

httpd error log

```
 [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 5153:tid 140323287488256] [client 10.x.x.x:53042] AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /var/www/html/test.php (Permission denied)'
```

php-fpm www-error.log

```
UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: And what do you mean when you say "same permissions"? Just the file mode (i.e. the number you set with `chmod`) or also the file owner? (i.e. the value you change with `chown`) Because for even half decent security PHP scripts should run using their own group/user. Run an `ls -l` to see if you _really_ set the same permissions and owner.

Comment: Owner too. I set it the same as the phpinof file only difference was the file name.

Comment: I've tried many different names. Also, tried different directories under www/thml. Also, installed a fresh version of Oracle Linux 9 and had the same problem as 8.8.

Comment: where can you find "permission denied" message? in browser? and could you describe more log file from nginx access log and error log?

Comment: I get the message in a browser. I added log info to the original post

Comment: Just checked and I did that already based on what i found on by googling, but forgot I did it. Guess I can't add a screenshot but my selinux config says [SELINUX=disabled]

Comment: Question: If you "copy" the working file (phpinfo.php) to another name (say using `cp -p phpinfo.php newtest.php`), will the newtest.php be working ? Pls test.

Comment: Looks like if I copy phpinfo.php to a new name it works. If I create a new file with the new name it does not work. 
Here's the permissions output. 

New created file (Not working)
-rw-r--r--. 1 root apache 23 Jul 14 08:09 newtest.php

Original file that works 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root apache 19 Jan 20  2020 phpinfo.php

copied (cp -p ) file that works 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root Apache 19 Jan 20  2020 newtest.php

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue! It seems that even though I disabled SELinux in /etc/selinux config with [SELINUX=disabled] it was still effecting the files.
I learned from another site the dot on the end of the permissions results (-rw-r--r--.) denotes the file is controlled but selinux.
I ran [ restorecon -r /var/www/html/test.php ] and it worked! Now I'll look at why disabling selinux didn't work.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Good to know that finally you know / confirm that it is selinux which is causing the issues. Next time, disable selinux (and reboot ONCE) right after the OS installation (before installing httpd / mysqld, etc.). Thanks